# Oracle Apex- set up calculations in grid

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with fixed rows.
I need to do calculations rowwise.

So the source query is:

```
select kpi,monthly,yearly from kpi where project_id = :P1_PROJECT_ID;
```

[image]

It looks in the grid like:

[image]

So, KPI Profit and Loss will be entered by user but for Gross, i need to use formula which auto calculates field.

Formula will be: Profit/Loss*100

So, when user types 20 in profit and 10 in loss it should calculated to 200.

So for monthly, it should take :

```
Profit(KPI)/Loss(KPI)*100
```

Similarly for yearly column:

```
Profit(KPI)/Loss(KPI)*100
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic action on the Amount column of IG for change event. Create a true action as Set Value. Set the type as PL/SQL expression. Specify the PL/SQL expression as :AMOUNT. Submit item AMOUNT. Set affected items Px_AMOUNT. Then create another true action to execute JavaScript code and add the following code in it:

```
var model = apex.region("igitems").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model;
var n_amt, n_totamt = 0;
col_amt = model.getFieldKey("AMOUNT");
model.forEach(function(igrow) {
    n_amt = parseInt(igrow[col_amt], 10);
    if (!isNaN(n_amt)) {
        n_totamt += n_amt;
    }
});
apex.item("Px_AMOUNT").setValue(n_totamt);
```